# Posicionamento do botão ao resize da tela

Tags: javascript, front-end, posicionamento, slide, resize

possuo um slide onde o botão deve sempre ficar posicionado de acordo com uma determinada imagem. Ao redimensionar a tela a posição da imagem é alterada fazendo com que o botão fique desalinhado sendo necessário dar um refresh na página para que volte a posição correta, tentei usar um `resize` porém a atualização do botão referente a imagem não ocorre, se alguém puder me nortear a solução ficaria grato.

```
/* Slide */

const btnPrevious = document.querySelector('#previous');
const btnNext = document.querySelector('#next');
const users = document.querySelectorAll('.user');
const screenWidth = document.querySelector('.container').clientWidth;
const arrUsers = Array.prototype.slice.call(users);
let currentUser = 0;

/* Quote */

const quoteTop = document.querySelector('.quote').getBoundingClientRect().top;
const quoteLeft = document.querySelector('.quote').getBoundingClientRect().left;
const imgQuote = document.querySelector('.imgQuote');

/* Buttons */

const buttons = document.querySelector('.buttons');
const image = document.querySelector('.imgUser');
const buttonsHeight = buttons.offsetHeight;
const buttonsWidth = buttons.offsetWidth;

const positionXBtn = image.getBoundingClientRect().left;
const positionYBtn = image.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;

/* Behavior's slide */

function addClass(index) {
  users[index].classList.add('active');
}

function changeClass() {
  arrUsers.forEach((element) => {
    element.classList.remove('active');
    addClass(currentUser);
  });
}

function handleClick(event) {
  if (event.target.id === 'next' && currentUser < users.length - 1) {
    currentUser += 1;
    changeClass();
  }

  if (event.target.id === 'previous' && currentUser > 0) {
    currentUser -= 1;
    changeClass();
  }
}

btnPrevious.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
btnNext.addEventListener('click', handleClick);

/* button position */

function btnAppear() {
  buttons.style.top = `${positionYBtn - buttonsHeight / 2}px`;
  if (screenWidth > 1024) {
    buttons.style.left = `${positionXBtn + 45}px`;

    imgQuote.style.top = `${quoteTop - 65}px`;
    imgQuote.style.left = `${quoteLeft + 125}px`;
  } else {
    buttons.style.left = `${screenWidth / 2 - buttonsWidth / 2}px`;
    imgQuote.style.top = `${quoteTop - 23}px`;
  }
}

btnAppear();

window.addEventListener('resize', btnAppear);
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenta adicionar um `seTimeout()` na `function btnAppear()`, para ele ficar chamando a função novamente posicionando o botão. Tente e ve se funciona.

```js
function btnAppear() {
  buttons.style.top = `${positionYBtn - buttonsHeight / 2}px`;
  if (screenWidth > 1024) {
    buttons.style.left = `${positionXBtn + 45}px`;

    imgQuote.style.top = `${quoteTop - 65}px`;
    imgQuote.style.left = `${quoteLeft + 125}px`;
  } else {
    buttons.style.left = `${screenWidth / 2 - buttonsWidth / 2}px`;
    imgQuote.style.top = `${quoteTop - 23}px`;
  }
  setTimeout(btnAppear,1)
}
```

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Infelizmente não funcionou, tentei mudar para o window.onresize porém também não funcionou. Usei um console.log para testar e o evento é disparado quando acontece o resize do screen, porém o style do elemento não é alterado.

Comment: Tenta ver se sua tag de script ta em cima do body, se estiver coloque a embaixo da tag body